# if a cell empty, move the value of the adjacent column to the row above

Tags: excel, vba

I have a dataset, column A has some empty cells. If there is a empty cell, I would like to move the value in column B to the row above, and clean the value in column B. I've figured out a code to do this when there is only one empty cell in column A. But it did not work when there are two or more empty cells in column A (I meant to move the values in column B to the row where column A is not empty; not the row above in this case). Can anyone help me tweak the code so that it can work on the other situation? Thank you.

My code is as following:

```
Sub MoveToRow()
Dim i As Integer
For i = 1 To 10


If IsEmpty(Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i)) = True Then
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & i).Offset(-1, 0) = Range("B" & i).Offset(-1, 0) & "/" & Range("B" & i)
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B" & i).Value = Empty

End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Dataset-Before

```
Sunday  work1
        work2
Monday  work3
Tuesday work4
        work5
Wednesday   work6
Thursday    work7
Friday  work8
```

Dataset-After

```
Sunday  work1/work2

Monday  work3
Tuesday work4/work5

Wednesday   work6
Thursday    work7
Friday  work8
```

Dataset- Did not work (because there are two empty cells below Sunday)

```
Sunday  work1  
        work2
        work3
Monday  work4
Tuesday work5 
        work6
Wednesday   work7
Thursday    work8
Friday  work9
```

Dataset- if it works

```
Sunday  work1/work2/work3  


Monday  work4
Tuesday work5/work6 

Wednesday   work7
Thursday    work8
Friday  work9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this a try:

```
Option Explicit

Sub MoveToRow()

Dim i As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim r As Range
Dim count As Integer

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
For Each r In ws.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp))
    If IsEmpty(r) Then
        count = count + 1
        With ws.Range(r.address)
            .Offset(-count, 1) = .Offset(-count, 1) & "/" & .Offset(0, 1)
            .Offset(0, 1).ClearContents
        End With
    Else
        count = 0
    End If
Next r

Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

You could also add some code in there to delete the left over empty rows if you like. But I'll leave that up to you to do. :-)

Comment: It works! You are so good! Left me a lot to study! Thank you so much!

Comment: May I ask how to learn VBA this well? Any recommendations on books or resources? I could not say enough to show my appreciation. Thank you so much!

Comment: @FeifeiZhang You're very welcome! Happy to help. I don't have any specific books to recommend but you could check out some books listed here: https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?url=search-alias%3Dstripbooks&field-keywords=Excel+VBA and read some of the reviews. Here are a few websites that are helpful: 1) http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/MainPage.aspx 2) https://www.youtube.com/user/WiseOwlTutorials. The Internet is filled with helps. :-)

Comment: This is very helpful! Thank you very much!